# Multi-Programming with OSMESA

Tags: c++, opengl

I have being trying to multi-program my software to run on different threads on my client machine with c++; and rendering opengl drawings off-scrren with OSMESA. Does anybody know if its theoretical possible to do this using OSMESA.

Thanks.

Comment: What is OSMESA? Are you talking about MESA? If so, where does the OS come from?

Comment: @NicolBolas: OSMesa is the Off-Screen software rasterizer backend of Mesa. It has a customary API for creating the OpenGL context. It's actually called "OSMesa" and Google leads you right to its project page at the Mesa homepage: http://www.mesa3d.org/osmesa.html